# Ruby: Call Get Value From Hashes In Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is probably a stupid one, but I'm missing something here...

I have this

```
users = [{name: "chris"}, {name: "john"}]
```

This works

```
users.map do |obj|
   puts obj[:name]
end
```

I want to do this

```
user.map(&:name)
```

tried the symbol to proc in many different ways with no luck. I can't think of a way to do this that makes sense, but I feel there is one.

Comment: When you give an example (generally a good thing), you should show your desired or expected result. It generally clarifies the question and does not take up much space. btw, it was good of you to define the variable `users`. That allows readers to reference it in comments and answers. All too often the variable is omitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to use `user.map(&:name)` you need a `name` method on every object inside your array.

Hash doesn't have a `name` method, but you could implement it (Don't do this, it's just an example):

```
class Hash
  def name
    self[:name]
  end
end
```

But a much better solution is to define a class for your names. Since this case is very simple a [Struct](http://www.blackbytes.info/2015/06/struct-and-openstruct/) will do.

Assuming these names belong to users or customers, you could do something like this:

```
User  = Struct.new(:name)
users = []

users << User.new('chris')
users << User.new('john')

user.map(&:name) # ['chris', 'john']
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought there might be a some magic that my do that on the fly. But this at least explains it to me. Thanks.

Comment: The question is how he can use `user.map(&:name)` in his code, he literally says 'I want to do this'. Exactly that code, that's not what the other answer is saying at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
user_names = users.map {|obj| obj[:name]}
#user_names = ["chris", "john"]
```

Will give you Array with all names

Answer (score 0):

You could use following syntax that is based on `lambda` and `proc`:

```
users = [{name: "chris"}, {name: "john"}]
p users.map(&->(i){i[:name]})
```

or

```
users = [{name: "chris"}, {name: "john"}]
p users.map(&proc{|i| i[:name]})
```

or

```
users = [{name: "chris"}, {name: "john"}]
name = proc{|i| i[:name]}
p users.map(&name)
```